# Passing a string variable into a function parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string-literals

I have a dozen or so trigger fields on a webpage that I'd like to consolidate. I'm attempting to add a **'data-target'** attribute to the HTML tags that have event listeners which will correspond to the target dom object to reveal when selected.

```
var target = this.getAttribute('data-target');

document.querySelector('#${target}');
```

In this case, I want to select the dom object with the ID that matches the data-target of the variable. Is it possible to use string literals like this in Javascript?

```
schedule_yes.addEventListener('focus', handleReveal);

function handleReveal(target){
    var target = this.getAttribute('data-target');
    console.log(target);
    let what_date = document.querySelector('#${target}');
    console.log(what_date);


<input class="form-check-input check" type="radio" name="is_schedule" id="schedule_yes" data-target="schedule_date"/>
```

Comment: string literals use back ticks, not single quotes: \`#${target}\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a template literal instead of single quotes:

```js
function handleReveal(target){
  var target = this.getAttribute('data-target');
  console.log(target);
  var what_date = document.querySelector(`#${target}`);
  console.log(what_date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Naming your parameter `target` just to overwrite it inside your function doesn't make any sense. Also to access data attributes the DOM element has a `dataset` property designed specifically for the purpose.

So here's the clean version:

```js
function handleReveal(){
  const { target } = this.dataset;
  // same as: const target = this.dataset.target;
  // same as: const target = this.getAttribute('data-target');
  console.log(target);
  const what_date = document.getElementById(target);
  console.log(what_date);
}


schedule_yes.addEventListener('focus', handleReveal);
```

```html
<input class="form-check-input check" type="radio" name="is_schedule" id="schedule_yes" data-target="schedule_date"/>

<div id="schedule_date">The TARGET</div>
```